# How to retrieve ArrayList<Item> from a separate class?

Tags: java, class, methods, arraylist

So there is a class called Server I can't access which has the method getGoodItems()

"public static java.util.ArrayList getGoodItems()

Returns an ArrayList of good items read from the database (csv file)."

And I want to make a goodItems arrayList in the class I'm writing with something like:

```
ArrayList<Item> goodItems = new ArrayList<Item> Server.getGoodItems();
```

I don't know what this line of code should look like so I create the arraylist I need in the class Im working with.  What is the right format here?

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Item> goodItems = Server.getGoodItems();
```

Should work.

You could use the interface as the type as well:

```
List<Item> goodItems = Server.getGoodItems();
```

This is helpful in the event you want to convert it to some other type of list. You can use the copy constructor of another implementation for that:

```
List<Item> goodItems = new LinkedList<Item>(Server.getGoodItems());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create any array. It should be created in `getGoodItems()`. Just do like this:

```
ArrayList<Item> goodItems = Server.getGoodItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `getGoodItems()` method is `static`. You do not need any object to access that method. So just call that method by class.

```
List<Item> gooditems=Server.getGoodItems();
```

Another thing is that you can do it by object also but the way to written is wrong. Just change the following code:-

```
ArrayList<Item> goodItems = new ArrayList<Item> Server.getGoodItems();
```

to--

```
ArrayList<Item> goodItems = new Server().getGoodItems();
```